# keeping the color of the source code in latex

Tags: color, sourcecode

Any idea how can we keep the color of the  python code we copy into latex? Please note I don't want to define the colors in Latex. Just want to keep the same colors shown in IDLE when I copy the code automatically. By the way, I'm using overleaf.

Comment: If you dont want to program, the only option would be to make a screenshot of your source code and incorporate the image into your tex document.

Comment: Because that was not a real answer, just a comment... seriously thou, the idea of tex is to have a common fixed layout for semantically similar things. To deviate from that given layout means to program those changes, this also counts for colours in source codes. It is rather unlikely that listings, minted or pygment packages provide the same colours you are looking for by their default setting, so you would need to program those colours anyway.

Comment: Thank you! It's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge overleaf does not allow editing code outside of latex, and only some heavy IDEs (which are not made for latex) manage to color program snippets inside other programs.

If your problem is to get the color on the pdf, either you insert an image (if you want to make sure the color of the pdf will be the same as the color of your IDE), or you use a package such as [listing](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) or [minted](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minted/minted.pdf), which will color the code on the pdf.